# EWS Managed API and Advanced Threat Protection (ATP) for email attachments

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices

Is there any way I can determine if the ATP scan on the attached file has completed? The problem is when I get a new email having attachments the EWS API shows the default ATP scan email as an attachment and not the actual attachment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what happens in EWS with ATP in place, the email notification fires again on completion of ATP scan. I had to look for this event and was able to replace the earlier email with ATP Scan in progress.eml as an attachment to the email having an actual attachment. It was a tedious process though.